# How to work inArray in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select id="select">
    <option value="1">1adsd</option>
    <option value="2">2adsd</option>
    <option value="3">3adsd</option>
    <option value="4">4adsd</option>
    <option value="5">5adsd</option>
</select>

var parray = ['2', '5'];
    $("#select").live('change', function(){
        if($.inArray($(this).val(), parray)){
            console.log('yes');
            console.log($(this).val());
            console.log(parray);
        } else {
            console.log('no');
            console.log($(this).val());
            console.log(parray);
        }
    })
```

Why this doesnt working correctly?

if i select value 1 this show me 'yes' but "1" isnt in parray.

if i select value 2 this show me 'no' but "2" is in parray.

if i select value 5 this show me 'yes' - only this is OK. Why?

LIVE:

http://jsfiddle.net/G5D2V/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [the manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) clearly states:

$.inArray returns -1 if the element is not found, or the index where the element has been found (beginning at 0) otherwise.

```
if($.inArray($(this).val(), parray) >= 0) {
```

Comment: 1 will evaluate to -1.  2 will evalutate to 0. 5 will evaluate to 1.  Only 0 is considered false implicitly by Javascript.

Comment: @GryzOshea The index of the element '2' in the array is 0, which in Javascript (and a lot of other languages) a `false` value. That's why the `if` condition fails for that element.

Comment: @GryzOshea, what's happening is that $.inArray(...) returns a value of -1 when the element is not found. In javascript, -1 is treated as true when its used in place of a boolean (any non-zero integer is true). See: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/

Answer (score 3):

[inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) returns -1 when the element is not found otherwise it returns found element's index.

```
var parray = ['2', '5'];
    $("#select").live('change', function(){
        if($.inArray($(this).val(), parray) >= 0){
            console.log('yes');
            console.log($(this).val());
            console.log(parray);
        } else {
            console.log('no');
            console.log($(this).val());
            console.log(parray);
        }
    })
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G5D2V/1/)

Answer (score 1):

$.inArray returns the item's position and not a boolean

```
$(function() {
    var parray = ['2', '5'];

    $("#select").on('change', function() {

        var value = $(this).val()
        var index = $.inArray(value, parray)

        if (index >= 0) {
            console.log('yes');
            console.log($(this).val());
            console.log(parray);
        } else {
            console.log('no');
            console.log($(this).val());
            console.log(parray);
        }
    })
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

`.inArray` returns the matched index or `-1` on no match.

So you either need to check if the result is greater than -1, or be cool and do with `~` negate.

```
if(~$.inArray($(this).val(), parray) ) { }
```

That bitwise operator actually will turn `-1` into `0` and any other positive match into its negative counterpart (minus one). Without describing this in too much detail with truthy and falsy values in ECMAscript, this will exactly do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if($.inArray($(this).val(), parray)!=-1)
```

as your condition (add the !=-1) to it.